# Добавление класса к повторяющимся элементам

Tags: javascript, jquery

В ссылках повторяется атрибут `href`:

```
<a href="img/slide-1-big.jpg"></a>
<a href="img/slide-2-big.jpg"></a>
<a href="img/slide-0-big.jpg"></a>
<a href="img/slide-1-big.jpg"></a>
<a href="img/slide-2-big.jpg"></a>
<a href="img/slide-0-big.jpg"></a>
```

Как к повторяющимся элементам добавить определенный класс? Например:

```
<a href="img/slide-1-big.jpg" class="1"></a>
<a href="img/slide-2-big.jpg" class="2"></a>
<a href="img/slide-0-big.jpg" class="0"></a>
<a href="img/slide-1-big.jpg" class="1"></a>
<a href="img/slide-2-big.jpg" class="2"></a>
<a href="img/slide-0-big.jpg" class="0"></a>
```

Значение `href` неизвестно.

Comment: по стандарту: пробегаем циклом. создаем объект для хранения ключ-значение. бежим циклом, читаем href. Если в объекте нет такого ключа - заносим, и параллельно даем значение для ключа.... если есть - пропускаем..........параллельно в цикле можно присваивать как раз и классы в соответствии со значением в ключе

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил, только скрипт добавляет не класс, а дата-атрибут.

```
    var hrefs = new Array(); // создаём массив
    var links = $('.picture a'); // заносим в переменную все ссылки
    $(links).each(function() { // для каждой ссылки выполняем функцию
        var href = $(this).attr('href'); // заносим в переменную значение текущего атрибута (для красоты)
        if ( $.inArray( href, hrefs ) == -1 ) { // ищем в массиве hrefs значение href
            hrefs.push( href ); // если отсутствует - добавляем в массив
        } // наш массив полон
    });
    $(links).each(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if ( $.inArray( href, hrefs ) !== -1 ) { // если в массиве есть наша ссылка
            $(this).attr('data-index',$.inArray( href, hrefs )); // присваиваем текущей ссылке data атрибут с индексом текущего атрибута href в массиве hrefs 
        }
    });
```

Comment: можно это собрать в один  цикл. `$.inArray` вам сразу дает индекс, если элемент найден, `push` вовзращает длину массива, следовательно и индекс известен. так что сразу `var index = $.inArray(...); if(index == -1) { index = hrefs.push(href) - 1; }` и `$(this).data('index', index)`;